# Accidentally deleted /dev/tty, how to bring it back on debian7?

Tags: debian, sudo

I am on debian 7 and accidentally delete `/dev/tty` so I cannot `sudo su` anymore. I can still ssh with my username however when I want to get root rights with `sudo su` I get following message:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

As the answer on my related post on SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021233/401025 says, I can create `/dev/tty` manually with

```
mknod /dev/tty c major 0
```

However I have to find out the major. Any ideas what number it might be on debian 7?

Comment: 5. It would really surprise me if it wasn't.

Answer (score 5):

From a debian 7 install:

```
$ ls -l /dev/tty
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Sep 10 14:50 /dev/tty
```

so do the following

```
mknod /dev/tty c 5 0
chmod 666 /dev/tty
chown root.root /dev/tty
```

This will create the character device, set ownership to root and change the mode to `rw-rw-rw-`.